# Graphics object is recognized as 'environment' type rather than 'list', thus not compatible with ggplot although it should be

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, environment-variables

I can't pass a graphics object to ggplot, and one symptom of the problem is that it's recognized as `environment` type, rather than `list`, but I'm not sure this is what causing the issue.

I use the `gamlj` package to generate a linear model of some data. The function `gamljGLM` returns a model and a plot, which is **supposed to be** compatible with ggplot functions. In other words, the plot generated by `gamljGLM` should return `TRUE` for `is.ggplot()`, but this isn't the case for me. Furthermore, when testing the plot object for its type, I get that `typeof()` returns `environment`, although in principle it should return `list`.

### Steps for reproducing the issue

1. Installing `gamlj` package (done successfully on R versions either 3.6.3 or 4.0.2)

```r
## first, install 'devtools' package
install.packages("devtools")

## second, install 'gamlj'
devtools::install_github("gamlj/gamlj")
```

2. Load some data

```r
library(tidyverse)

day_1 <- rnorm(1000, mean = 77, sd = 18)
day_2 <- rnorm(1000, mean = 74, sd = 19)
day_3 <- rnorm(1000, mean = 80, sd = 5)
day_4 <- rnorm(1000, mean = 76, sd = 18)


df <- 
  cbind(day_1, day_2, day_3, day_4) %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  gather(., key = day, value = mood, day_1:day_4) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(day), factor)

> df

## # A tibble: 4,000 x 2
##    day    mood
##    <fct> <dbl>
##  1 day_1  88.2
##  2 day_1  66.7
##  3 day_1  67.0
##  4 day_1  93.8
##  5 day_1  70.6
##  6 day_1  97.9
##  7 day_1  81.9
##  8 day_1  91.2
##  9 day_1  69.4
## 10 day_1  48.4
## # … with 3,990 more rows
```

3. Model the data using `gamlj::gamljGLM`

```r
p <- gamljGLM(df_as_df, 
              formula = formula("mood ~ day"), 
              plotError = "ci", 
              plotHAxis = "day")

> p

## GENERAL LINEAR MODEL

##  Model Info                                    
##  ───────────────────────────────────────────── 
##    Info                                        
##  ───────────────────────────────────────────── 
##    Estimate          Linear model fit by OLS   
##    Call              mood ~ 1 + day            
##    R-squared                      0.01558849   
##    Adj. R-squared                 0.01484944   
##  ───────────────────────────────────────────── 


##  MODEL RESULTS

##  ANOVA Omnibus tests                                                        
##  ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────── 
##                SS            df      F           p             η²p         
##  ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────── 
##    Model          16406.19       3    21.09267    < .0000001    0.0155885   
##    day            16406.19       3    21.09267    < .0000001    0.0155885   
##    Residuals    1036048.90    3996                                          
##    Total        1052455.08    3999                                          
##  ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────── 


##  Fixed Effects Parameter Estimates                                                                                                          
 ## ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────## ───────────────────────────────── 
##    Names          Effect           Estimate      SE           Lower        Upper         β              ## df      t              p            
 ## ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────## ───────────────────────────────── 
##    (Intercept)    (Intercept)      76.9554387    0.2545935    76.456293    77.4545841     0.00000000    ## 3996    302.2678295    < .0000001   
##    day1           day_2 - day_1    -2.1270930    0.7200993    -3.538889    -0.7152967    -0.13111742    ## 3996     -2.9538885     0.0031563   
##    day2           day_3 - day_1     3.3874303    0.7200993     1.975634     4.7992266     0.20880663    ## 3996      4.7041156     0.0000026   
##    day3           day_4 - day_1    -0.6973011    0.7200993    -2.109097     0.7144952    -0.04298275    ## 3996     -0.9683401     0.3329331   
 ## ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────## ─────────────────────────────────
```

Upon running `p`, along the model above, it automatically draws the plot too. In addition, the plot can be called directly by `p$descPlot$plot`.

[image: p$descPlot$plot]

4. Passing the plot object to `ggplot` fails

```r
p$descPlot$plot + xlab("blah_x_label")

Error in p$descPlot$plot + xlab("blah_x_label") : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

So I check this out:

```r
> is.ggplot(p)

## [1] FALSE
```

And furthermore:

```r
> typeof(p)

## [1] "environment"   ## in principle, this should be 'list'
```

### To sum up

This plot should be of ggplot type, and a friend has been successful in applying ggplot functions onto `p$descPlot$plot`, because the function is designed to plot a ggplot object. But for me it fails. I'm aware that this is a specific case with a specific package. I've contacted the package maintainer, and even opened an issue on its github project, but so far haven't been responded. I'm posting this question here too since I hope that maybe this issue, although specific, lies on a more general principle of ggplot objects, which could be solved regardless of being familiar with this specific package/function. Any ideas?

Comment: This doesn't seem to work as intended. You can use `gamlj_ggplot(p)$fun() + xlab("blah_x_label")`.

Comment: Wow this is amazing.  It's working!  I absolutely didn't notice the `gamlj_ggplot()` function. But then what's the mechanism of adding `$fun()`? Could you write an answer?

Comment: It should work as `gamlj_ggplot(p) + xlab("blah_x_label")`. I'd say this is a bug. The maintainer should fix this before they submit to CRAN.

Comment: Looking at the readme on github I wonder if this even supposed to be run from R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the new versions (>2.1.1) it should be solved